# MikroORM - How to map a raw database result into a DTO object?

Tags: node.js, mikro-orm

Does MikroORM expose simple DTO mapping functionality as Hibernate does?

I am looking for a way how to map a raw database result automatically into a DTO object using the declared mapping.

I am looking for something similar to `EntityManager.map` but which does not merge and ideally does not require the DTO class to be declared as an entity.

Using `EntityManager.map` is not an option because I need to map thousands of objects and the performance impact of using it is huge.